# How to specify a single particular point with a star Listplot?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I wish to specify a particular point (x,y) in Mathematica Listplot with different Plotmarker such as a star. I have tried using Epilog, it works in highlighting the point with a different colour but I cannot make the point as star. Someone please help.

The particular point should be represented as a star but PlotMarkers doesn't work inside Epilog and the point is still circular.